# How to retrieve Custom Metadata Type records in VS Code Using Package.xml

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code, custom-metadata

I have created a `My_Custom_Metadata__mdt`(Custom Object) in a Salesforce org, also I have created a few records under this custom metadata. Now I want to retrieve these records in VS Code so that I can store those in the GitHub repo as well transfer them to another org using VS Code.

As we can add these records directly in Change Sets is there any option to retrieve these in VS Code?

I tried adding the below code in the `package.xml` but that is not working.

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>My_Custom_Metadata__mdt</name>
</types>
```

Is this possible? If yes what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two steps to address it

- Include Custom Metadata Type schema in package.xml using CustomObject
  tag
- Include Custom Metadata Type records in package.xml using CustomMetadata tag

You have to add the package xml like below:-

```
  <types>
        <members>Salesforce_Feature.Einstein_Wave</members>
        <members>Salesforce_Feature.Platform_Shield</members>
        <members>Salesforce_Feature.Sales_Cloud</members>
        <members>Salesforce_Feature.Service_Cloud</members>
        <name>CustomMetadata</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Salesforce_Feature__mdt</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
```

you will be able to retrieve then. Check this [link](https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/how-to-retrieve-and-deploy-custom-metadata-types-using-ant/)

Comment: Thanks, Sanket, this is exactly what I was looking for!